# How to pull values from an array of objects with key pairs inside?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, firebase

As part of my application I would like to extract the values for `monthlyIncome`, `savePercent` and years and save them as `$scope`. values so they can be set as default values when a user logs in!

```
[
    {
        "$id": "date",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 1457178818625
    },
    {
        "$id": "email",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "a@b.com"
    },
    {
        "$id": "firstname",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "test"
    },
    {
        "$id": "lastname",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "Isaacs"
    },
    {
        "$id": "monthly",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 328947
    },
    {
        "$id": "monthlyIncome",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 123
    },
    {
        "$id": "percent",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 10
    },
    {
        "$id": "regUser",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0"
    },
    {
        "$id": "savePercent",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 10
    },
    {
        "$id": "years",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 40
    }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not executable code.

Comment: I run out of "flags", so please rethink your question. It's very hard to follow and understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Question is far too vague. Where is the data shown being used if not passed to scope already? Why isn't this all one object in the first place?

Comment: Sorry if was confusing guys... I'm quite new to programming (as you can see!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you store your array in `$scope.data` property. Then all you need is to check every object in this array. You can use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function to loop through array and check each object.

Check this plunker [plnkr.co/edit/WeQhCb?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/WeQhCb?p=preview)
or following code:

```
//for each object in data array
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
  // check if value id is equals to 'monthlyIncome' OR 'savePercent' OR 'years'
  if (value.$id == 'monthlyIncome' ||
      value.$id == 'savePercent' || 
      value.$id == 'years') {
    // add it's value with the same key (e.g. $scope.monthlyIncome)
    $scope[value.$id] = value.$value;
  }
});
```

---

And now it's in a `$scope`

```
monthlyIncome: {{monthlyIncome}}
savePercent: {{savePercent}}
years: {{years}}
```

---

Or more elegant way to check properties is add required props in array and check is it in. Full code:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('appController', function($scope, $log) {
      $scope.data = [{
        "$id": "date",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 1457178818625
      }, {
        "$id": "email",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "a@b.com"
      }, {
        "$id": "firstname",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "test"
      }, {
        "$id": "lastname",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "Isaacs"
      }, {
        "$id": "monthly",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 328947
      }, {
        "$id": "monthlyIncome",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 123
      }, {
        "$id": "percent",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 10
      }, {
        "$id": "regUser",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": "4157e8b1-efa2-4feb-bf75-e907c0e200e0"
      }, {
        "$id": "savePercent",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 10
      }, {
        "$id": "years",
        "$priority": null,
        "$value": 40
      }];

      // required properties for $scope
      var propertieIDs = ['monthlyIncome', 'savePercent', 'years'];

      //for each object in data array
      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
        // check if value id is in 
        if (propertieIDs.indexOf(value.$id) !== -1) {
          // add it's value with the same key (e.g. $scope.monthlyIncome)
          $scope[value.$id] = value.$value;
        }
      });

    });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was after :)